# Casting error in my form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `ComboBox` in a `DataGridView`.  However I get an error when I run it:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox'.

What can I do to resolve this error?

```
 ComboBox comboBox;
    private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Control is ComboBox)
        {
            comboBox = e.Control as ComboBox;

            if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex >= 0)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Edit Control Showing");
                comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged -= new EventHandler(comboBoxItems_SelectedIndexChanged);
                comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(comboBoxItems_SelectedIndexChanged);

            }
        }
    }

    void comboBoxItems_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            int comboBoxSelectedIndex = ((ComboBox)sender).SelectedIndex;
            string comboboxSelectedValue = ((ComboBox)sender).SelectedText;
            int gridViewSelectedRow = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;
            if (comboBoxSelectedIndex >= 0 && gridViewSelectedRow >= 0)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ComboBox Index - " + comboBoxSelectedIndex);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("GridView Index - " + gridViewSelectedRow);
                if (comboBox != null)
                {
                    comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged -= new EventHandler(comboBoxItems_SelectedIndexChanged);



                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception E)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: You can't cast a `ComboBox` to a `DataGridView` any more than you can turn a cat into a dog. If you **post your code** that triggers this exception, then we can tell you what you're doing wrong.

Comment: You can cast a Cat into a Dog if Cat derives from Dog though =P

Comment: On which line you are getting the exception? Where the comboBox variable declared? what is the type of it?

Comment: exception in " int comboBoxSelectedIndex = ((ComboBox)sender).SelectedIndex;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would also recommend checking the `sender` object before attempting to cast it (would confirm what decyclone mentioned in his answer in addition to preventing casting errors):

```
if(sender is ComboxBox) {
      //cast
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this method is also registered to an event of type `DataGridView`. That is why when you try to cast it (*sender*) to `ComboBox`, it throws an exception. Because, in that case, *sender* is of type `DataGridView`.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. The `sender` will be the `DataGridView` that is raising the event, not the combo box.

Answer (score 0):

I think somehow you have set the comboBoxItems_SelectedIndexChanged event handler to the DataGridView itself. Check the properties window of DataGridView and if it's there, remove it.
Also I recommend using "as" keyword for casting and checking it for "null".